# Get headers from Initial Page Request

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get headers information when I go to my navigator and access my server application: locahost/8080.

```
X-CSRF-HEADER:X-CSRF-TOKEN
X-CSRF-PARAM:_csrf
X-CSRF-TOKEN:c2a7ba83-a93a-4090-874a-8550b49e0d90
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Javascript question, unless I'm missing something. If you're using Chrome, you could try the "Network" tab. It will show all requests and server replies, together with the headers and the data.

Comment: What is my navigator? :)

Comment: hum i want to use the information in my javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Solution is to get

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
```